# Angularjs - load element based on json input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I have a situation where I receive a json object and within json data is a section that look something like this

```
{
  "elName": "elCst3",
  "label": "Label 3",
  "type": "input",
  "content": "some text",
}
```

This is assigned to `$scope.data`

The **type** expression in the object can be `input` or `textarea`

In my html template, depending on which value the TYPE is I am supposed to load either a textfield (input/text) or textarea element.

*Pseudo logic of it is something like this..*

```
IF {{data.type}} == "input" then

    <input id="data.elName" type="text" value="{{data.content}}">

ELSE IF {{data.type}} == "textarea" then

    <textarea id="data.elName">{{data.content}}</textarea>
ENDIF
```

How could I in the best and simplest way approach this in Angularjs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `ng-if` in your case. Something like:

**HTML**

```
<label ng-repeat="val in list">
    <div ng-if="val.type == 'input'">
        <input id="data.elName" type="text" value="{{val.content}}"></input>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="val.type == 'textarea'">
        <textarea id="data.elName">{{val.content}}</textarea>
    </div>
</label>
```

**JS**

```
 $scope.list = [{
        "elName": "elCst3",
            "label": "Label 3",
            "type": "input",
            "content": "some text for input"
    }, {
        "elName": "elCst4",
            "label": "Label 3",
            "type": "textarea",
            "content": "some text for textarea"
    }];
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/869/)**</kbd>

Comment: I'll try this out and come back to comment. thanks! Could you just hint at what "fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope'];" does?

Comment: @PersistentNewbie its just injection of scope. You can remove it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch into different HTML parts dependent on the JSON data you try to show in the view, `ngSwitch` is an option:

```
<div ng-repeat="val in list">
    <div ng-switch="val.type">
        <div ng-switch-when="input">
            <input type="text" value="{{val.content}}"></input>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="textarea">
            <textarea cols="40" rows="5">{{val.content}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default>
            Unknown val type: {{val.type}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By the way: [I had a similar question ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295564/angularjs-dynamic-html-dependent-on-json-data)