# angularjs: dynamic html dependent on json data

Tags: html, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to show the content of my json model in a dynamic way, depending on the provided json. I use `ng-repeat` to loop through my data and want to display a html template to fill with data dependent on the encountered data type.

JSON

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "input-text",
            "desc": "Full Name"
        },
        {
            "type": "input-checkbox",
            "desc": "Accept Terms"
        }
    ]
}
```

This should result in different html code, appropriate filled with the json content.

E.g.

```
<div><label>Full Name</label> <input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"> <label>Accept Terms</label></div>
```

Right now what I do is to use an angularjs directive to create an element and add the json values to the right spot. `e.g. element.html('<div><input type="checkbox"> <label>' + scope.item.desc + '</label></div>')` That seems like the jquery way (or worse) to do it although I want to do it the 'right' angularjs way.

How can I use a different HTML template filled with content, dependent on the encountered JSON data?

PS: The above example is a simple one, the encountered data is far more complex than switching the position of the `label` and `input` field.

Comment: You can use resource for getting json, if you want to use different json, you could do just .../:name.json. Seems here's the right example https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_08.

Comment: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/
This should be what you want.

Comment: Just for reference: I know how to http.get() the json, fill my scope and ngRepeat over the elements , just the part to use different HTML blocks (with data) bothered me. Thanks @Huy for linking your helpful article and also the comments there help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution seems to use [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) with different HTML paths, e.g.:

```
<div ng-switch="item.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="input-text">
      <div><label>{{item.desc}}</label> <input type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="input-checkbox">
      <div><input type="checkbox"> <label>{{item.desc}}</label></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>Unknown item.type: {{item.type}}</div>
</div>
```

Seems the approach using an angularjs directive (which I took first) may be a good solution for complex scenarios as "Huy Hoang Pham" points out in his blog post: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/ (thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set the data on the scope, then use the [`ng-repeat` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)  in your HTML to output it:

Controller:

```
.controller('MyData', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myModel = {
        elements: [ { desc: .. }, .. ]
    };
})
```

You would be using the [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) or some other appropriate method in this controller to populate `myModel` with data, but in the end the data needs to end up on the `$scope` object somehow. Then it's the template's job to display that data:

```
<div ng-controller="MyData">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="element in myModel.elements">
            {{ element.desc }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```